# How to make jQuery .slideToggle() appear to slide instead of collapse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/v127pe9v/

The slide works as designed but if you notice it appears it's collapsing in on top of the items inside the sliding box. I'd like to know if there's a way to make the slide look uniform as it's going up and down.

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".slide-box").slideToggle("down");
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<button>Click</button>
<div class="slide-box">
    <input placeholder="Enter text">
    <input placeholder="Another text">
    <input placeholder="Third text">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.slide-box {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: none;
    padding: 30px;
}
.slide-box input {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

EDIT: Adding an image that hopefully illustrates what I'm asking:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I believe your issue is the padding you have on the slide-box.

http://jsfiddle.net/v127pe9v/1/

I changed your CSS to this and I think that is the effect you are looking for?

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.slide-box {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: none;
}
.slide-box input {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: What if we keep the padding, any other way to fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think so. jQuery Slide Up/Down works by animating over the height, margin and padding properties. So as long as the element you want to animate with slideUp or down has top/bottom padding or margining jQuery will animate those values. Only way to avoid it is to compensate another element with those properties as I did with margining on the input.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've already covered this because something was telling me it was a padding issue. That does look better, but not exactly what I was trying to describe. Think of a drawer, as you open the drawer, everything inside is moving outwards at the same rate because they are contained inside the drawer. The effect slideToggle is showing is like the contents remain in place but the box is closing up and down. Does that make sense?

Comment: That does make sense. I'll play around with it if I can find time and see. Unfortunately I still think because of how jquery animates the top and bottom padding/margins you will never truly get that effect without writing your own. In other words not using slide toggle and maybe just the animate function.